# Load Data Reader into Postgres Using COPY STDIN

Tags: c#, postgresql, oracle, npgsql

I want to load millions of records from an Oracle table into a Postgres table in the quickest and most convenient way using a C# console app. Ideally I don't want to COPY out to a .CSV file and then load back in as I am not sure about the necessary permissions on the target server. Is it possible to do it via an Oracle datareader? This is what I have tried so far (The SQL query columns names are named as such to show the datatypes in Oracle)

```
public void RunExportPackage()
        {

            var sql = "SELECT NUMBER(10,0), CHAR(3), VARCHAR2(10), NUMBER, CHAR(1) FROM TABLE";

            using var sourceConnection = new OracleConnection(_appSettingsOptions.ConnectionStrings.OracleConnection);

            OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand(sql, sourceConnection);
            
            sourceConnection.Open();

            using (OracleDataReader oracleReader = com.ExecuteReader())
            {

                using (NpgsqlConnection targetConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(_appSettingsOptions.ConnectionStrings.PostgresConnectionDEV))
                {
                    targetConnection.Open();
                    
                    using (var writer = targetConnection.BeginBinaryImport("COPY TABLE FROM STDIN BINARY"))
                    {
                        writer.WriteRow(oracleReader);
                    }


                }

            }

        }
```

When I try this I am getting this error.

**IEnumerable parameters are not supported, pass an array or List instead**

The column types in the postgres table are

[image]

If someone could just point me in the right direction that would be great :)

Comment: Create a database link in Oracle to PostgreSQL and then push the data from Oracle to PostgreSQL and do not use C# at all.

Comment: Its got to be a console app which will run on a visual cron schedule

Comment: Create a database link from Oracle to PostgreSQL and then use a console app to connect to Oracle and tell Oracle to push the data from Oracle to PostgreSQL without sending any data through the console app. Or, alternatively, set up a scheduled job in Oracle to run on the same schedule as your cron schedule and then you do not need the console app.

Comment: I'd be curious about how one "tells Oracle to push data to PostgreSQL without sending any data through the console app".

Comment: BeginBinaryImport is likely the right direction, but you can't pass an OracleDataReader directly into WriteRow like that: WriteRow accepts a an object array. You can probably get the current row as an object array via [DbDataReader.GetValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getvalues?view=net-6.0#system-data-common-dbdatareader-getvalues(system-object())).